# Convert from std::string to LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to get the version from a dll file, here is my code:

```
std::string getVersionNumber()
{
    LPCTSTR  pFilePath = L"C:\\File.dll";
    boost::filesystem::path full_path( boost::filesystem::current_path() );

    std::string dllFile = full_path.string() + "/File.dll";

    DWORD dwDummy;

    DWORD dwFVISize = GetFileVersionInfoSize( pFilePath, &dwDummy );
    LPBYTE lpVersionInfo = new BYTE[dwFVISize];
    UINT uLen;
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *lpFfi;

    GetFileVersionInfo( pFilePath , 0 , dwFVISize , lpVersionInfo );
    VerQueryValue( lpVersionInfo , L"\\" , (LPVOID *)&lpFfi , &uLen );

    DWORD dwFileVersionMS = lpFfi->dwFileVersionMS;
    DWORD dwFileVersionLS = lpFfi->dwFileVersionLS;

    delete [] lpVersionInfo;
    std::ostringstream stringStream;

    stringStream << HIWORD(dwFileVersionMS) << ".";
    stringStream << LOWORD(dwFileVersionMS) << ".";
    stringStream << HIWORD(dwFileVersionLS) << ".";
    stringStream << LOWORD(dwFileVersionLS);

    return (stringStream.str());
}
```

if I try calling `GetFileVersionInfoSize` and `GetFileVersionInfo` with `pFilePath` as the first parameter, it compiles and runs perfectly.
However, if I try calling them with `dllFile`, it (of course) doesn't compile, and any attempt to somehow convert `dllFile` to `LPCTSTR` gives me rubbish unicode characters.

I'm kinda lost, any ideas?

Comment: If you had Googled it, you would have found your answer.  I found the dupe by merely Googling the title of you question.

Comment: Stating that *"it doesn't compile"* without providing the exact compiler message is a cardinal sin, the punishment for which is typically nasal demons.

Comment: I googled it in many various ways and came up with nothing that works. All it gives me is a conversion from string to LPCSTR while I need it to be LPCTSTR. And there compilation error I get is: 'GetFileVersionInfoSizeW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'LPCWSTR'.

Comment: You don't need it to be `LPCTSTR`, just say `DWORD dwFVISize = GetFileVersionInfoSizeA( dllPath.c_str(), &dwDummy );`

Comment: Or use `full_path.wstring()` (and change types to `std::string` as appropriate)